XAMARIN How to share a database between android and home computer over wifi without SSMS installed?
I am able to share a SQL Server database installed on Windows PC and Windows Form app with Android application using WI-FI and IP address. But I would have to distribute the application and I can't ask every user to install SSMS. Is there a possibility to do this without SSMS even using other types of databases?
I tried with SQLite in xamarin +windows forms but they can't connect. Is it not possible in Xamarin to point with IP address to my MYDB.db3? Any other super lightweight databases? I just need to exchange data...

so every user is going to have to install an app on their PC and their phone?  And the app will only be usable when the phone is on the same local network as the PC?

Yes. With my Xamarin app I take photos and at the same time combine other parameters that I save in a sqlite database on Android (photos in binary format). Then I download everything with one tap to my sql database on windows pc on the same wifi network.

The app works independently. the data is downloaded to the sqlite database. Only when I want to download them to the SQL database
they must be on the same network

expose the db on the PC via a webservice.  Depending on the size and complexity of the data you could use MySQL or SQLite or any DBMS

Thanks jason. I have never worked with web services and it will be hard and difficult but I will try to study them. Programming is actually not my first job but it is my first passion. Hi

with "ConnectionStrings": {
"DefaultConnection": "Filename= C:\SQLITE\sqlite.db" in appsettings.json  of webservice i can connect correctly to my sqlite dbfile in pc. How i can specify the IP address for call the service from xamarine?

use HttpClient.  There are thousands of existing questions on using webservices in a .NET environment
